# Viewing followers without access token

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I know that the API can produce a list of followers from `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` but this requires an access token so I can only view the followers of an account that authorises me to do so. However, since this information is already public for instagram accounts such as [this](https://www.instagram.com/luissuarez9/followers/) is there a way to grab the list of followers without the account holder's (Suarez's in this example) access token? I only need the account names (I know that `followed_by` will return their full names, bio etc).